# How to generate a PDF with a single table with page borders tight around it?

Tags: tables, geometry

This is the opposite of commonly asked questions:  I don't want a LaTeX table to fit on the page, instead, I want the page to fit tightly around a single table in all 4 directions.  In essence, I want LaTeX to generate tables for me, however without all the extra white regions around the table.

As a MWE, see the code below that generates a table in the middle of a large white sheet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    0.1      & 0.2      & 0.3      \\
    0.4      & 0.5      & 0.6      \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output of the code above:

[image: Output of the code above.]

Expected output:

[image: Expected output.]

Comment: `standalone` class instead of `article`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need a float, `standalone` is your friend. Observe that there is no `table`, but only `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lll}
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
    \hline
    0.1      & 0.2      & 0.3      \\
    0.4      & 0.5      & 0.6      \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```